# Creating Qt Statically "The system cannot find the specified file"

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator, qt5

After running `configure -static` in `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source`, I ran `mingw32-make`. and I get this error (at the bottom of image).

[System cannot find the specified file http://puu.sh/3tSh4.png](http://puu.sh/3tSh4.png)

What files am I missing? I am using Qt 5.1.0, I have downloaded `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-rc2.zip` and extracted it into `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source`, Installed Perl64 in `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\`, ran the prompt as admin, and I have followed this guide:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#linking-the-application-to-the-static-version-of-qt

Comment: That might be well a bug in Qt (static linking wasn't well tested at least for a while), so better report it as bug before Qt 5.1.0 is released.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Zlatomir told me that I needed python. Is that the case? Or do you still think it may be a bug? I'm not quite sure where to install python to test out this theory. If you could guide me :) hehe

Comment: Reading the error in more detail, it indeed looks like one needs python now. See the `python` in the line after `CreateProcess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building v8 needs python installed and in path make sure that you have it, see more information [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) especially the requirements to build Qt on [windows](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#aea23489ce3aa9b6406ebb28e0cda430).

Comment: As far as I know, Python is just needed for Webkit and building a static Webkit is a heavy task/not the best idea

Comment: @Albertus it's needed for QML/Quick too, and anyway since we know only that the OP run: _configure -static_ that as far as i know builds webkit too.

Comment: how would I skip building a webkit?

Comment: pass _no-webkit_ as configure option (with static and other options you need), here is a documentation link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html (it's for Qt 4, i can't find it quickly for Qt 5 so you might search a little for other version 5 specific options, but no-webkit shouldn't be changed)

Comment: but V8 build is needed for QML/Quick modules too, so you still need Python.

Comment: I have python installed elsewhere on my computer. Do I need to install it in a specific directory? 2.7 right?

Comment: I installed 2.7 in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source` and ruby in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\Ruby200` Ran mingw32-make, but there is not a -no-webkit option at all... :(

Comment: yea, I installed it in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source and it didn't work, same error.

Comment: is python added to the path too? In that link it says that it needs to be in the path, also check that documentation page ans see if you didn't skipped something else - also did you run _mingw32-make clean_ before re-configure and re-build.

Comment: mingw32-make clean takes over a day to clean.... could I just uninstall, clear registry and reinstall?

Comment: my path `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\Ruby200\bin;%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts;C:\cygwin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\`

Comment: epic, i'm not really sure about that, but i think you can just delete the whole folder and after that just unzip the sources again, did you tried to rebuild the Qt sources that installs with the "sdk" or did you downloaded the sources only? Anyway, if you don't used the source code only, download and try that and as i said, i'm not sure that the delete is cleaning well (but logically it should because the configure shouldn't modify your system, it most likely only modify the makefiles that are used later to build Qt)

Comment: yea, that's my impression too, I downloaded the sdk, and the sources individually. something like "qt sources everywhre 5.1.0" and the actual sdk without the sources that came with it installed.

Comment: @Zlatomir http://puu.sh/3vXUa Notice the line just above "WARNING:" It says my additional libraries are located in `-LC:\MySql\lib` but what I typed was http://puu.sh/3vXXo.png